# selectively disable akismet

Tags: comments, users, akismet

I need to disable Akismet for comments written by one of my registered users, since there is a problem that when such plugin is enabled they do not appear. I have some familiarity with php but I am unable to understand the right place to insert my if condition. Where can I add my little piece of code to prevent Akismet recalling?

Comment: If Akismet is flagging a user it might be wise to figure out why before moving forward.

Comment: Sometimes Akismet is wrong. *I've* even been flagged by Akismet before.